# Unable to call a method from another class

Tags: c#, datetime, methods, argument-passing

I have a program in which the user enters a username and a date and then clicks a button which inputs the data into a database.

The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to pass the text box date data as an argument in a method to my BOL class.  I get the following error: "Member 'P90XPRogramt.ProgramLoginBOL.TestParsing(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead"

Here is the code from my UI layer:

```
public partial class ProgramLoginForm : Form
{
    private ProgramLoginBOL busObject =
        new ProgramLoginBOL();       

    //default constructor
    public ProgramLoginForm(string dayNo)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        busObject.InitializeConnection();
    } 

    private void btnBeginProgram_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        busObject.UserName = txtEnterName.Text;            

        busObject.TestParsing(txtStartDate.Text);            

    }

    //event handler to close program
    private void btnExitProgram_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }        
}
```

Here is the code for my BOL class:

```
class ProgramLoginBOL
{
    //declare variables
    string userName = "";

    //instantiate a connecttion object to Access database
    OleDbConnection aConnection =
        new OleDbConnection(
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            "Data Source=P90XDatabase.accdb;");

    public ProgramLoginBOL()
    {
    }

    //property for userName variable
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return userName; }
        set { userName = value; }
    }

    public static DateTime TestParsing(string datetext)
    {
        DateTime dt;

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(datetext, "d", null, 0, out dt))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parsed to {0}", dt);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bad date");
        }
        return dt;
    }

    public void InitializeConnection()
    {
        ProgramLoginDAL.InitializeConnection(aConnection);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what it is telling me to do.  By type name I assume they mean data type, so I tried the following:

```
string busObject.TestParsing(txtStartDate.Text);

string.busObject.TestParsing(txtStartDate.Text);

string.TestParsing(txtStartDate.Text);

busObject.TestParsing(string txtStartDate.Text);
```

None of these have worked.  I also tried using DateTime instead of string.  As I said, I'm at a loss as to what it wants me to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static methods can't be called with instances of a class exactly as error message says.

```
P90XPRogramt.ProgramLoginBOL.TestParsing(txtStartDate.Text);
```

For future errors try searching for error code first - normally MSDN article contains explanation and sample, like in this case [CS0176](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhcxt2bd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I wasn't aware that the MSDN had error code explanations.  I will do that in the future.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

The method you are trying to call is a `static`-method and not an instance-method.

The method TestParsing should be called on the `class` `ProgramLoginBOL` and not on a concrete instance, like this:

```
ProgramLoginBOL.TestParsing(txtStartDate.Text);
```

Static methods are used when no specific attributes of an instance are required.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I will make the appropriate changes

Answer (score 4):

It wants you to change:

```
busObject.TestParsing(txtStartDate.Text);
```

to:

```
ProgramLoginBOL.TestParsing(txtStartDate.Text);
```

Since `TestParsing` is a static method of the `ProgramLoginBOL` class, and not associated with a specific instance.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I will make the appropriate changes

Answer (score 1):

Your method is static, you cannot use an instance of that class to call it. Do this

```
ProgramLoginBOL.TestParsing("text to pass");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call static methods with class name rather class object
so try

```
ProgramLoginBOL.TestParsing(txtStartDate.Text);
```